# Python requests, post multipart/form-data encoded with utf-8

Tags: post, utf-8, python-requests, multipartform-data

I have the following data that I need to send it in the form of post request to a server that accepts multipart/form-data

```py
data = ( ('key1', (None, 'some_data')),
  ('key2', (None, ' ™ ™ ™ data contains Unicode characters ™ ™ ™ ')),
)
```

I'm using python3.7

```py
import requests
requests.post(url, files=data)
```

The server currently is not recognizing the `™` character.

Comment: Why do you use the the `files=` parameter for this? The strings aren't file objects. I think you want to use the `data=` parameter. The data will be form-encoded by the requests library.

Comment: @lenz Please, Could you provide the syntax needed to be encoded, I tried using data= parameter but it didn't work

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Please be more specific: Is there an exception? Is the result different from your expectation?

Comment: @lenz, It didn't throw an exception, the server still read it as ASCII, the syntax I used is the following request.post(url, data=dict(**{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2™ '}))

Comment: You need to verify if this is an error on the client or the server side. If you want to get help here, you need to give more details about what goes wrong in which ways (please edit the question post).

Comment: Please describe why you think the server misrecognises that character. Describe exactly how you analysed what the server does.

Comment: because it's a non-ASCII character, I need to encode it as utf-8, the server is reading `™` as `â¢`

Comment: This looks like the server receives UTF-8 but interpretes it as Latin-1, then converts it to lowercase. Try this: `'¢'.encode('utf8').decode('l1').lower()`.

Comment: Looks like the problem is on the server side.